# Can't use some D3DFORMAT's for textures

Tags: c++, image, colors, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to load in different textures with different formats, however, only a couple format that only have R,G and B values work. Formats like A1R5G5B5 don't seem to work at all.

I'm trying to add these formats to regular d3d9 textures:

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texpage;
D3DXCreateTexture( device, 512, 512, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, group->format, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &texpage )
```

So straight to the question, which conditions do I have to meet to get those formats working?

Comment: The Direct3D device has to support it as a render target. Most Direct3D 9 era hardware did support ``D3DFMT_R5G6B5`` for rendering. You need to check for support via ``IDirect3D9::EnumAdapterModes``. A better option is to use Direct3D 11 instead and learn about [Direct3D hardware feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186615.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly I'm forced to use D3D9. So this is all dependend on hardware? Nothing on code? Alpha is what matters to me the most, alpha + R5G5B5 / R3G2B3 or anything other than 8 would be amazing. I will definitely check out EnumAdapterModes

Comment: Why are you forced to use D3D9? Do you have to support Windows XP Service Pack 3 or Windows Server 2003 SP1?

Comment: I'm writing this for a DLL for an engine that already exists. I'm not going to create my own engine.

Comment: Ok, so ancient game engine :)

Answer (score 0):

You said in the question you are attempting to load textures, however, you are attempting to create the textures with the `D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET` flag. Render targets generally have much less compatibility than textures used for sampling. Although `A1R5G5B5` [shows][2] that it is a backbuffer format, its support is (obviously) not universal, in fact, Direct3D9 does not guarantee support for any specific format.

If you remove this requirement, you will receive better compatibility, however, as I said, you're still not guaranteed that every device will support this format. You can check the compatibility using [IDirect3D9::CheckDeviceFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174309(v=vs.85).aspx). If the format is not supported, I would suggest pre-converting the file you are loading offline to a better supported format as a fallback (for instance, I have not seen a driver where A8R8G8B8 is not supported).